# Subscribe to a child-link of the sdf model in Gazebo-simulated world

Tags: python, publish-subscribe, ros

I have Baxter robot (Baxter SDK urdf) and a joystick model (simple sdk file) simulated in Gazebo. What needs to be logged is the position of the joystick stick pitch and roll, which are displayed in Gazebo.

(I can't record the log of the world in Gazebo because Baxter SDK uses Gazebo version 2, and this feature doesn't work well there).

The sdf of the joystick looks like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version='1.4'>
  <model name='joystick'>
    <link name='joystick_base'>
      <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
      <inertial>
        <pose>0 0 0.75 0 -0 0</pose>
        <mass>0.01</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.0001</ixx>
          <ixy>0</ixy>
          <ixz>0</ixz>
          <iyy>0.0001</iyy>
          <iyz>0</iyz>
          <izz>0.0001</izz>
        </inertia>
      </inertial>
      <collision name='joystick_base_collision'>
        <pose>0 -0 0.77 0 -0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>0.07 0.07 0.04</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <visual name='joystick_base_visual'>
        <pose>0 -0 0.775 0 -0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>0.07 0.07 0.05</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <velocity_decay>
        <linear>0</linear>
        <angular>0</angular>
      </velocity_decay>
    </link>
    <link name='link_roll'>
      <pose>0 0 0.05 0 -0 0</pose>
      <inertial>
        <pose>0 -0 0.75 0 -0 0</pose>
        <mass>0.01</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.0002</ixx>
          <ixy>0</ixy>
          <ixz>0</ixz>
          <iyy>0.0002</iyy>
          <iyz>0</iyz>
          <izz>0.0002</izz>
        </inertia>
      </inertial>
      <velocity_decay>
        <linear>0</linear>
        <angular>0</angular>
      </velocity_decay>
    </link>
    <joint name='joint_roll' type='revolute'>
      <child>link_roll</child>
      <parent>joystick_base</parent>
      <axis>
        <xyz>0 1 0</xyz>
        <limit>
          <lower>-1.2</lower>
          <upper>1.2</upper>
          <effort>15</effort>
          <velocity>4</velocity>
        </limit>
        <dynamics>
          <damping>0.7</damping>
        </dynamics>
      </axis>
    </joint>
    <link name='joystick'>
      <pose>0 0 0.05 0 -0 0</pose>
      <inertial>
        <pose>0 -0 0.75 0 -0 0</pose>
        <mass>0.01</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.0002</ixx>
          <ixy>0</ixy>
          <ixz>0</ixz>
          <iyy>0.0002</iyy>
          <iyz>0</iyz>
          <izz>0.0002</izz>
        </inertia>
      </inertial>
      <collision name='joystick_collision'>
        <pose>0 -0 0.835 0 -0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <length>0.17</length>
            <radius>0.01</radius>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
      </collision>
      <visual name='joystick_visual'>
        <pose>0 -0 0.835 0 -0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <cylinder>
            <length>0.17</length>
            <radius>0.01</radius>
          </cylinder>
        </geometry>
      </visual>
      <velocity_decay>
        <linear>0</linear>
        <angular>0</angular>
      </velocity_decay>
    </link>
    <joint name='joint_pitch' type='revolute'>
      <child>joystick</child>
      <parent>link_roll</parent>
      <axis>
        <xyz>1 0 0</xyz>
        <limit>
          <lower>-1.2</lower>
          <upper>1.2</upper>
          <effort>15</effort>
          <velocity>4</velocity>
        </limit>
        <dynamics>
          <damping>0.7</damping>
        </dynamics>
      </axis>
    </joint>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

I would like to subscribe to the `'joint_pitch'` and `'joint_roll'` to receive their values, e.g. something like:

```
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose, PoseStamped
model_coordinates = rospy.ServiceProxy('/gazebo/get_model_state', GetModelState)
resp_coordinates = model_coordinates('joystick', 'joint_roll')
print(str(resp_coordinates.axis.position.x))
```

Any ideas how do this so that it actually works?

Comment: Do you want to listen to link or joint states? Your title says link, but your question asks for joints.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know the current joint properties (position and rate), you can just request the Gazebo service `/gazebo/get_joint_properties`.
You just have to write a python service client as explained [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29), or you can also first try to get the information via `rqt_service_caller`.